# Angular4 component dies, lifecycle hooks not firing after navigating from and then back

Tags: angular, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

What could go wrong, if the component lifecycle events are not fired (except `ngOnDestroy`) on second and onward activation of the component? I made a simplified test case with very similar setup: http://plnkr.co/edit/0CTtzFbaJPHYRvhzogtS?p=preview and that works...
But not my real code. I can see only these events:

[image]

In the later cases the content is not correctly rendered either: it is rendered only what's before the first binding. But there is no any error message or warning during compilation or in the browser console.

The major difference between the setup from above and the original code is that tha later is webpacked.

Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: If navigation only changes a parameter value, but doesn't actually navigate to a different route, the component is reused. Not sure if this is the case here

Comment: It is not the case, actual navigation happens as in the linked test case.

Comment: Where do you navigate from and to, to get above behavior? What buttons do you click on what order?

Comment: Unfortunately the demo is not producing this behavior. I could not reproduce in a separate setup yet. I will recreate my project from scratch to see...